# Laravel swap the position in collection - multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.4

Following is the array in the collection:

```
array:1 [▼
  "online" => array:2 [▼
    "IS-003" => array:19 [▼
      "product" => Product {#831 ▶}
      "quantity" => 1
      "payment-option" => "online"
    ]
    "HA4" => array:19 [▼
      "product" => Product {#822 ▶}
      "quantity" => 1
      "payment-option" => "online"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Whenever a user changes the `payment-option`, accordingly the above array should change.

For instance, if `HA4['payment-option']` is changed from `online` to `cod`, then there should be 2 arrays in parent array.
Following is the array that I want as result.

```
array:2 [▼
  "online" => array:1 [▼
    "IS-003" => array:19 [▼
      "product" => Product {#831 ▶}
      "quantity" => 1
      "payment-option" => "online"
    ]
  ]
  "cod" => array:1 [▼
    "HA4" => array:19 [▼
      "product" => Product {#822 ▶}
      "quantity" => 1
      "payment-option" => "cod"
    ]
  ]
]
```

The thing that I have tried so far but couldn't get the desired result:

```
$paymentOptionCart = collect();

foreach ($cart as $paymentType => &$details) {
    foreach ($details as $c => $p) {
        if ($c == $code) {
            $details[$c]['payment-option'] = $request->option;
            $paymentOptionCart->put($paymentType, $details);

            unset($details[$c]);
        }
    }
}
```

On executing the above code, nothing happens except the `payment-option` is updated to `cod`.

I know I am making a silly mistake somewhere, but I am unable to locate where and how.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: `$paymentOptionCart->put($paymentType, $details);`, `$paymentType` is your current paymentType yes? So it makes sense if it doesn't move

Comment: @KendrickKesley even if I do `$request->option`, it never changes.. I don't know why..

Comment: I'm just confirming if you change `$paymentType` inside `$paymentOptionCart->put($paymentType, $details);` to `$request->option`. you'll get the same result as when you use `$paymentOptionCart->put($paymentType, $details);`?

Comment: please show us how you are getting the array at the first place

Comment: @KendrickKesley yes, I do get the same result..

Comment: @Sohel0415 This is a cart function, and it is getting values from many places in the application.. Like products table, users table, product_pricing table, etc. I have cut it down to simple and upto the need only..

Comment: @SaiyanPrince have a look at my answer, it should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your task:

```
$array = [
        "online" => [
            "IS-003" => [
                "quantity" => 1,
                "payment-option" => "online"
            ],
            "HA4" => [
                "quantity" => 1,
                "payment-option" => "online"
            ]
        ]
    ];


$code = "HA4";
$request_option = "cod";

foreach ($array as $paymentType => $details) {
        foreach ($details as $c => $p) {
            if ($c == $code) {
                $array[$request_option][$c] = $p;
                $array[$request_option][$c]["payment-option"] = $request_option;
                unset($array[$paymentType][$c]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: here `$array` is the array that you give on the first place and i have tested it, it should work

Comment: @SaiyanPrince I have updated my answer with complete tested code, you may change according to your need as i don't have any idea about your full data

Comment: Hey.. Can you please explain me the code that you wrote.. I want to know the mistake (of any kind) that I was making.. I was trying to crack this since days without any result..

Answer (score 0):

`unset($details[$c])` seems to be the problem... this punches out the element at index 0, at the end of the first iteration - and index 1 should then become index 0, which subsequently will not be accessible at index 1, during the next iteration of the loop. just run the loop until the exit condition is met and then unset them all, not during the loop... or loop backwards, in order to keep the indexes intact; this would unset the last one element at first and the loop would not exceed the array boundaries.

having two different payment options within a single online order is rather an unlikely example, haven't seen this yet. people might rather post two orders (which implies, not only the business logic is flawed, but the array structure has an unfortunate design, which requires such messing around).

[xdebug](https://xdebug.org) is great for understanding what is happening. even if my answer might not answer the question in code one can copy & paste (that's not my job), xdebug will tell you exactly what the problem is.